# Notepad++ : Convert EOL from Windows to Unix after document has been created?

Tags: windows, bash, notepad++

I created a Bash script in Notepadd++ and did so mistakenly under `EOL conversion > Windows`. I then run it on Bash but there were many problems and errors (for example, each empty row with a single tab indent appear as a dot).

A deep checking with `cat -v` exposed some Windows-like formatting hidden characters in the file, added by Notepad++ that inserted some hidden windows-formatting characters causing the file to be misinterpreted by bash.

Even though I already changed EOL mode to Unix, it seems the entire file is still formatted in a Windows fashion. I can now delete all tabs and carrige returns and save anew but is there an automatic way to change it to Nix formatting that you know of?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) to convert your file to Unix format.

Alternatively, in Notepad++ check what the Encoding is set to - ideally you'll want UTF-8 (use "Convert to UTF-8" in the Encoding tab).

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to fix using basic text manipulation tools. Any of the command below will fix your file:

1. sed:

   ```
   sed -i 's/\r//' file.sh
   ```
2. perl

   ```
   perl -i -pe 's/\r//' file.sh
   ```
3. tr

   ```
   tr -d $'\r' < file > newfile && mv newfile file
   ```